# Why does Jupiter break comets apart?

Tags: asteroids, comets, jupiter, tidal-forces

I understand that there are magnificent tidal forces that come with getting too close to Jupiter, but what is causing comets like Shoemaker-Levy to get torn apart?

I wouldn't expect that the gravitational forces are so strong that spaghetification occurs, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is.  Tidal disruption occurs when $\rho_{Jup}(R_{Jup}/R)^3$ > $\rho_{comet}$ where R is the separation and $\rho$ is the density.  The density of Jupiter is 1.33 g/$cm^3$ and the comet was estimated to have a density of only 0.5 g/$cm^3$ based on the radius at which it disrupted.  That is, disruption took place at separation R ~ $(1.33/0.5)^{1/3} R_{Jup}$.

Comment: The rubble pile model of comets is taking a bit of a beating these days from Rosetta - 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko, but the density of that oddly shaped object is still only 0.4 g/cc. It can't be *too* well cemented together. http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko